# XCode Base SDK changed - but source control has no changed files

Tags: ios, xcode

I was updating to XCode 9 and have some errors now in my app. The biggest problem I have however is: the Base SDK (and with that a big dependency) changed, but my git shows me no changed files. So Later I can´t retrace why those problems occured, because in my source control history there is no commit that an SDK was changed.

Does anyone know how to tell my git that the base SDK changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just saw an option that solves the problem:

In my Build Settings, The Base SDK was set to `Latest (iOS 11.0)`. In the raw file, this value is just `iphoneos`, a environment variable which points to the latest SDK.

Just set it to `iOS 11.0`, then it is hard set to this SDK, making it trackable in version control.